# First Web Application and Just need to know the First Step

Tags: javascript, html, web

The app is named "my name." (how original) 
I have been learning Java, C++ and other languages in my university but I have not learned how to tie it all together and the internet is actually being counterproductive because it's telling me too much with all the buzzwords like (anguarjs, JSP, swing, Ajax, etc) and I'm just really lost.

The app wants to do very simple things:

1. The screen will literally just have my name written in it: John Doe.
2. Every click will *randomize* and change the typeface of each letters such that J will be in Comic Sans, o will be italicized, h will be in boldface Times New Roman, n would be in blue, etc.
3. Mouse movement will change the background color in smooth realtime fashion.

I frankly can't get hold of what my workflow should look like..

What s my first step? And maybe right after that? What tools do I need? I assume HTML and JavaScript? It's very simple and the fact that I can't do this really frustrates me. Preferably, I'd like to use new and popular methods like HTML5.

Comment: This question is not a very good fit for SO, which is not designed to provide tutorial kind of information. I'd recommend you find a good intro to HTML/JS and walk through it.

Comment: I did not seek to get a tutorial - I just needed to know what my first step is so I can start learning that. Per your answer, HTML/JS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, HTML + javascript. I would recommend you using at least [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as you can get and modify HTML elements easily but you can go with just HTML + css + js (it's slightly harder).

With jQuery you can listen to page events, like `click`.

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    // Change text attributes. For example if you
    // have <p id="name">John Doe</p>, you can
    // change attributes like that:
    $("#name").css("font-family", "comicsans or something");
})
```

For the mouse move take a look at [mousemove event](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/).

You will ran into a lot of problems and I recommend you being patient taking into account you are learning from those mistakes.

Comment: Beautiful. HTML, JavaScript, and JQuery. I'm going to read the documentations. It is extremely daunting trying to figure out what comes first. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Any time. Also, to clarify other concepts, nowadays web development is focused at server/client apps. For that you use regular HTTP calls or AJAX. AJAX is javascript sending a query to a server in the background. Client/server technologies include `php`, `rails`, etc. Also there are single page applications (SPA) that use AJAX and that includes `angularjs`, `meteor`, `react`, etc. That's a _very_ rough recap.

Comment: It's 2016, not 2009.

Comment: @torazaburo what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that jQuery would have been a good recommendation in 2009. It's an old technology that is fading away.

Comment: Please @torazaburo, could you tell me an alternative that I should instead be learning??

Comment: Plain old HTML and CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @habs I recommended jQuery to solve your current problem. Also, it might be obsolete, but you will encounter examples and code using it  everywhere, here in 2016. The basics of how you make it work can be learned in minutes and it's all you need to know. Using plain javascript to solve the problem is harder and I don't see the point to discard learning jQuery basics just because _it's not cool anymore_.